# Google Closure Compiler to concatenate files using requirejs

Tags: requirejs, google-closure-compiler

I am using Google Closure compiler to concatenate and minify files. I am using require and my module depends on some JS files. Part of the JS files belong to an internal  JS framework and several others depend on modules which our team has written. My aim is to concatenate all the dependencies in 1 file and then minimize it. Following is the code (the files prefixed with 'oj' are the framework files)

```
define(['ojs/ojcore',
'knockout', 
'jquery', 
'generalApp', 
'modules/helpers',
'modules/facade/mrd',
'modules/facade/trf',
'modules/facade/crf',
'modules/models/sm',
'modules/models/mm',
'modules/list/dls',
'modules/utils/cm',
'ojs/ojchart',
'ojs/ojmasonrylayout',
'ojs/ojmenu',
'ojs/ojbutton',
'ojs/ojfilmstrip',
'ojs/ojarraytabledatasource',
'ojs/ojselectcombobox',
'ojs/ojdialog',
'ojs/ojcheckboxset',
'ojs/ojpagingcontrol'
], function (oj, ko, $, app, helpers, mrf, trf,crf, sm, mm, dls, cm) {
});
```

These files are in-turn dependent on other JS files and I only want the dependent JS files to get concatenated in the final JS file. Any idea how to do the concatenation using the Google Closure Compiler?

I tried using --process_common_js_modules --transform_amd_modules flags but the compiler threw errors since its unable to find the framework files which are located under ojs. There is a requirejs configuration file in which we are declaring path variables but I dont know how to specify the config file during the concatenation process.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Closure-compiler does not know how to order dependencies natively with AMD modules. Instead, use the requirejs compiler to concatenate the files in the correct order and then use closure-compiler for minification. This is done by setting the requirejs `optimize` flag to `none`.